# With Beautifulsoup, Extract Tags of Element Except Those specified

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beutifulsoup 4 and Python 3.5+ to extract webdata. I have the following html, from which I am extracting:

```
<div class="the-one-i-want">
    <p>
        content
    </p>
    <p>
        content
    </p>
    <p>
        content
    </p>
    <p>
        content
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>
            list item
        </li>
        <li>
            list item
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class='something-i-don't-want>
        content
    </div>
    <script class="something-else-i-dont-want'>
        script
    </script>
    <p>
        content
    </p>
</div>
```

All of the content that I want to extract is found within the `<div class="the-one-i-want">` element. Right now, I'm using the following methods, which work most of the time:

```
soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').findAll('p')
```

This excludes scripts, weird insert `div`'s and otherwise un-predictable content such as ads or 'recommended content' type stuff.

Now, there are some instances in which there are elements other than just the `<p>` tags, which has content that is contextually important to the main content, such as lists.

Is there a way to get the content from the `<div class="the-one-i-want">` in a manner as such:

```
soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').findAll(desired-content-elements)
```

Where `desired-content-elements`would be inclusive of every element that I deemed fit for that particular content? Such as, all `<p>` tags, all `<ol>` and `<li>` tags, but no `<div>` or `<script>` tags.

Perhaps noteworthy, is my method of saving the content:

```
content_string = ''
for p in content:
    content_string += str(p)
```

This approach collects the data, in order of occurrence, which would prove difficult to manage if I simply found different element types through different iteration processes. I'm looking to NOT have to manage re-construction of split lists to re-assemble the order in which each element originally occurred in the content, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of tags that you want:

```
 content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').find_all(["p", "ol", "whatever"])
```

If we run something similar on your question url looking for p and pre tags, you can see we get both:

```
   ...: for ele in soup.select_one("td.postcell").find_all(["pre","p"]):
   ...:     print(ele)
   ...: 

<p>I'm using Beutifulsoup 4 and Python 3.5+ to extract webdata. I have the following html, from which I am extracting:</p>
<pre><code>&lt;div class="the-one-i-want"&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        content
    &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        content
    &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        content
    &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        content
    &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;ol&gt;
        &lt;li&gt;
            list item
        &lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;li&gt;
            list item
        &lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ol&gt;
    &lt;div class='something-i-don't-want&gt;
        content
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;script class="something-else-i-dont-want'&gt;
        script
    &lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        content
    &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
<p>All of the content that I want to extract is found within the <code>&lt;div class="the-one-i-want"&gt;</code> element. Right now, I'm using the following methods, which work most of the time:</p>
<pre><code>soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').findAll('p')
</code></pre>
<p>This excludes scripts, weird insert <code>div</code>'s and otherwise un-predictable content such as ads or 'recommended content' type stuff.</p>
<p>Now, there are some instances in which there are elements other than just the <code>&lt;p&gt;</code> tags, which has content that is contextually important to the main content, such as lists.</p>
<p>Is there a way to get the content from the <code>&lt;div class="the-one-i-want"&gt;</code> in a manner as such:</p>
<pre><code>soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').findAll(desired-content-elements)
</code></pre>
<p>Where <code>desired-content-elements</code>would be inclusive of every element that I deemed fit for that particular content? Such as, all <code>&lt;p&gt;</code> tags, all <code>&lt;ol&gt;</code> and <code>&lt;li&gt;</code> tags, but no <code>&lt;div&gt;</code> or <code>&lt;script&gt;</code> tags.</p>
<p>Perhaps noteworthy, is my method of saving the content:</p>
<pre><code>content_string = ''
for p in content:
    content_string += str(p)
</code></pre>
<p>This approach collects the data, in order of occurrence, which would prove difficult to manage if I simply found different element types through different iteration processes. I'm looking to NOT have to manage re-construction of split lists to re-assemble the order in which each element originally occurred in the content, if possible.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? It should loop through the content adding the text you want while ignoring the div and script tags.

```
for p in content:
    if p.find('div') or p.find('script'):
        continue
    content_string += str(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that quite easily using

```
soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
desired-tags = {'div', 'ol'} # add what you need
content = filter(lambda x: x.name in desired-tags
      soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want').children)
```

This will go through all *direct* children of the `div` tag. If you want this to happen recursively (you said something about adding `li` tags), you should use `.decendants` instead of `.children`. Happy crawling!